# Edit line a textfile using linux shell

Tags: linux, shell, sed, edit

I need to change an IP-address in a text-file using linux-shell. How can I do that? Do you know a great source for regular expressions?

the textfile.txt contains sth like this:

```
# text text ffeefe 
Whatever text text ffeefe 
# text text ffeefe 
#
IPAddress : 192.168.200.40
#
# text text ffeefe
#
Whatever text text ffeefe 
# text text ffeefe
```

This is what I am looking for:

```
sed -i / find XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX / 192.168.200.41 / textfile.txt
```

The IP could be anything in that format XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX e.g. 192.168.200.40

Comment: it looks like you already have it, don't you? `sed -i 's/FIND/REPLACE/' file`.

Comment: it is not clear if the ip is  this 192.168.200.40 or 192.168.120.12 or something else.

Comment: Does it occur only once in the file? Does it occur after a specific content? Does it need to check if the line is commented or not? Provide more detail.

Comment: Does it occur only once in the file? Yes. Does it occur after a specific content? no. new line. Does it need to check if the line is commented or not? yes. it has to check if the line is commented.

Comment: You might use `awk` or `ed`

Comment: if only 1 ip in text, then checking is line commented is unneeded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although *fedorqui* is  right with asking more information about occurring of IP after specific content, I'll provide (easy) solution for finding any IPv4 string.

The expression is:

```
[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+
```

using it in sed looks like this:

```
sed -i -r 's/[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/newip/' file
```

On the other hand, if this is fixed "IPAddress : " before IP, then the OP should just use the IP they want.

Answer (score 0):

This will find line beginning with `IPAddress :` and change the digits to the new IP.

```
sed -i -r '/^IPAddress :/s/[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/192.168.200.41/' textfile.txt
```